# What is layout-square orientation in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

The Android system uses the default `layout` directory whether the user is using the application in a portrait or landscape mode, but we can customize our application to use a specific design when the user is in the landscape mode by using the `layout-land` directory, so what about the `layout-square` directory as I didn't find any resource explaining it.

[image: Creating new resource directory using the layout-square directory]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, it is possible to create a device with a screen that has the same dimensions on both axes: a square screen. Such a device would not really have "portrait" and "landscape".

The `-square` resource set qualifier would be used for resources optimized for that form factor.

Since ~0% of Android devices have square screens, I estimate that ~0% of Android apps have `-square` resources.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, it is possible to create a device with a screen that has the same dimensions (or almost the same dimensions) on both axes: a square screen. Such a device would not really have "portrait" and "landscape"; but there are definitely cases where you might want to provide fluid layout for square displays (or prevent such displays from using layout-landscape resources).

Foldable devices have screens that are either square or vanishingly close to square. Distinctly greater than 0% of all devices use this format. And it will only increase over time. And devices with foldable aspect-ratios often require fluid UI adjustments for the foldable display.